# AWS CLI returning No Such Bucket exists but I can see the bucket in the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to learn terraform and running through some examples from their documentation. I am trying to move a file from my pc to a S3 bucket. I create this bucket with the command:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket=terraform-serverless-example --region=us-east-1
```

If I then check on the console or call the `s3api list-buckets` I can see it exists and is functional. I can also upload using the console. However when I try to run this command:

```
aws s3 cp example.zip s3://terraform-serverless-example/v1.0.0/example.zip
```

It returns this error:

```
upload failed: ./code.zip to s3://test-verson1/v1.0.0/code.zip An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

I have tried to configure the region by adding it as a flag, have made sure permissions are correct and so on and it's all set up as should be. I cant figure out why this maybe and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What happens when you add `--region=us-east-1` to the `aws s3 cp` command?

Comment: The bucket name in the error message does not match the bucket name in the command you say that you are running.  Please ensure that what you've provided in the question exactly matches what you attempted to do.

Comment: @MarkB same error

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Just noticed that, really weird. Not sure why its trying to add to that bucket when the bucket im giving as the argument is different